# Get an attribute from an element in a xml file which is called by random in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, domparser

i want to get the id of a xml element and i don´t know how to acess it..
I am calling the element by random so i don´t know how i can get the current element information

To understand what i am doing have a look at my code:

I´ve got a xml file with 2 informations (a youtube link and a related id) like this:

```
<videos>
   <video id="0">o6f9wJ1DWhY</video>
   <video id="2">sp_WV91jx8E</video>
   <video id="3">plWnm7UpsXk</video>
   <video id="4">a1Y73sPHKxw</video>
   <video id="5">9avT0e5KPPU</video>
   <video id="6">VTO5yiN1b-I</video>
   <video id="7">HnENgvGFc4</video>
   <video id="8">d8u4CEBVq7s</video>
   <video id="9">abRplCazEjk</video>
</videos>
```

In the next step i am saving the information of an extern xml file in a variable

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
type: 'POST',       
url: "freeakshow.xml",
dataType: 'xml',
global: false,
async:false,
success: function(data) {
    return data;
}
}).responseText;

xml_string = jqxhr;
```

Then i am using the DOMParser to save the links in an array, so i can access them later

```
function get_ids_from_xml_string(xml_string) {
// Parse the XML string into a XMLDocument
var doc = window.DOMParser
            ? new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml_string, 'text/xml')    // Standard
            : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM').loadXML(xml_string); // IE

// Find the answer nodes
var id_nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName('video');
var videos = [];

// Loop through them and save their text content into an array
for (var i = 0; i < id_nodes.length; i++) {
     videos.push(id_nodes[i].firstChild.data)
}

return videos;
}

var videos = get_ids_from_xml_string(xml_string);
```

After that i am getting a random link from the array, so i can use it to play it with the Youtube API but this doesn´t matter right now

```
function getId() {
  return videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
```

And here is the question: How can i get the id of the current random link which i got from getId()

I want to display it in a div so i can see which id is the current and which id was the last one

(To understand what this is about, i want to display the current and last id of the random playing videos)
    }

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to "displaying" data for debugging is to use the console in the Developer Tools in Chrome (or a similar console or Firefox or IE). You can write a line like this

```
Console.log(getId());
```

Then it will print out in the console for you to see. The Web Developer tools in chrome are Tools > Developer Tools. Here is a good article which extensively covers the console in Chrome https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console.

If you have your heart set on displaying the information in a div, you can use a div set like this.

```
<div id="getIdOutput"></div>
```

Then javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("getIdOutput").innerHTNL = getId()
```

To display the output of getId()!

Comment: This is nice to know, but i want to put the ids in a div so i can display them on the website, its not for debugging :) i need the current id and the last id to display them. And i won´t get the id of the link because getId is only returning the link and not the related id. Bad naming here sry

Comment: i don´t want to display the output of getId(), i want to output the id of the link which getId gives me.. have a look at my xml file at the top. first i need to read-out the id of the link. gedId should be named getVideoLink

Answer (score 0):

You can update your getId function to store the id that it randomly produced.
Example:

```
var currentId, lastId;

function getId() {
  //save the prev id in the lastId variable
  lastId = currentId;
  //get a new id and store it
  currentId = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
  //return the corresponding video
  return videos[currentId];
}
```

Now you can use the currentId and the lastId, to match your needs

Comment: this would work perfectly in case getId would give me the id i want, again it´s bad naming sorry.. getId only returns the link and not the id i want.. i want to connect the id with the link, you can see it in my the xml file like  <video id="0">o6f9wJ1DWhY</video> .. i don´t have the related id for the link, i don´t know how to access it